# Invertible Matrices and Proving The Operations Equal to Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Show that if $A$, $B$, and  $A + B$  are invertible matrices with the same size, then

$$A(A^{–1} + B^{–1})B(A + B)^{–1} = I.$$

This is what i got:

$$A^{-1}A+B^{-1}ABA^{-1}+B^{-1}B = I$$

$$I+B^{-1}ABA^{-1}+B^{-1}B = I$$

$$B^{-1}ABA^{-1}+I = I $$

$$B^{-1}ABA^{-1} = I $$

$$I = I$$

$$I$$

So i have to write in proof form.

Comment: I don't follow all of your steps.  It might be easiest to multiply on the right side by $A+B$ and see that the left-hand-side expands to $A+B$.  Then, you can work backwards.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$A(A^{-1} + B^{-1})B = (AA^{-1} + AB^{-1})B = (I + AB^{-1})B = IB + AB^{-1}B = B + A,$$

post-multiplying by $(B + A)^{-1}$ gives

$$A(A^{-1} + B^{-1})B(B + A)^{-1} = I,$$

or

$$A(A^{-1} + B^{-1})B(A + B)^{-1} = I.$$

Comment: OK, I'll delete it, since it's corrected.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing looks tricky to me. It looks like you're assuming commutation of matrix multiplication, which doesn't generally hold. What does hold is distributivity (with respect to addition), i.e. $ A (B+C)=AB+AC $. We can use this to find:
$$ A (A^{-1}+B^{-1}) B (A+B)^{-1}=(AA^{-1} B+AB^{-1} B)(A+B)^{-1} =(B+A)(A+B)^{-1}$$
And now, since matrix addition ís commutative:
$$=(A+B)(A+B)^{-1}=I $$

Comment: I think i understood.